# Best way to store and use SCSS global variables for a AngularDart 5

Tags: sass, angular-dart

I’m using **AngularDart 5** in order to create a web app. I want to store some SCSS variables in my `styles.scss` file (`web` folder). What is the best way to use these variables in the SCSS stylesheet of a component (`lib` folder)?

Thank you!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are a couple of concepts I need to clear up first:

- Scss variables are only available at compile time. Once the file is compiled to CSS they are not available at runtime.
- Dart has a convention where only files in the lib/ directory can be imported to other places in the app. I believe that dart-sass enforces this convention, and you won't be able to import the file from web.

So your options are:

- Move the styles.scss file to the lib directory so that it can be
  imported. Convention is to have it start with an underscore which
  signals it is just for imports.
- Use CSS Variables which can be used
  at runtime.

Comment: Thank you! I found your answer very useful.